# Django- adding to server header (CORS)

Tags: ajax, django, django-cors-headers

I am getting a CORS error as my browser doesn't like localhost domains for Ajax.

*I believe* I need to add these to the server header so I can test locally.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

How to I write this in Django and what file does it belong in- middleware.py?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Answer (score 0):

Pip install not needed. Firstly, add this line to your setting.py

Settings.py-------------

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
    'myapp.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
)
```

Then create a file called "middleware.py" inside your "myapp" folder

Middleware.py in "/myapp" dir-----

```
class CorsMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
        #response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        #response['Accept'] = 'application/json'
        return response
```